# Mysql: Query Optimization Issue

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  CA.*,  O.id_enterprise ,O.sell_date,O.input_date
FROM            tempdb.CallsData_ CA
LEFT JOIN       tempdb.Outcomes_final O                             
                ON       CA.AgentLogin = O.agent_ 
                AND      CA.id_enterprise = O.id_enterprise
                AND      O.Outcome_generated_time >CA.Call_Starttime
                And      O.Outcome_generated_time <= CA.NextCall
```

I want to optimize this query when I do explain it gives me following result

[image]

These indexes are added

```
ALTER table tempdb.Outcomes_final add index `idx8`
      (`agent_`,`Outcome_generated_time`,`id_enterprise`);
ALTER table tempdb.CallsData_ add index `idx9` 
      (`AgentLogin`,`Call_Starttime`,`NextCall`,`id_enterprise`);
```

Are indexes hitting? and what does ALL in tpe column means? Also how can I optimize it

Comment: ALL means you're doing a full table scan. You're reading 2 million rows. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: The output of the `EXPLAIN` query is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).

Comment: No `WHERE` clause? There is not much to optimize on a query without a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You really want to output a million records? What are you going to do with that?

Comment: yes I need that output thats our process

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `EXPLAIN` query is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).

#### How to read the output of `EXPLAIN` for your query

MySQL computes the resultset one row at a time. To compute one row, it consults the tables one by one, in the order listed by `EXPLAIN`.

It starts with table `tempdb.CallsData_` (`CA`). The value `ALL` for [`type`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types) is the worst possible type. It means it has to do a full table scan (i.e. read all table rows one by one) in order to find the candidate rows for the result.

This happens because `CA` is on the left side of a `LEFT JOIN` (i.e. all the rows from `CA` appear in the resultset, even if they don't have a match in the right-hand side table) **and** the query doesn't have a `WHERE` clause (that could reduce the set of candidates).

Because `type=ALL` and there is no `ORDER BY` clause `possible_keys` is `NULL`. It doesn't make any sense to read an index **and** the table date when reading only the table data is enough.

`key` and `key_len` describe the index chosen (there is no index used to read the `CA` table, as said above).

The value of `rows` tells how many rows MySQL expects to read from the table. All the rows from the table in this case. The value is an approximation, it may not match the number of rows in the table exactly.

**There is nothing you can improve on table `CA` to make this query run faster.** The index `idx9` is not useful for this query. It only takes space and processing power (to be updated).

On the next step, after it reads a row from the first table, MySQL searches the candidate rows from the second table (`O`).

#### The second table

The value `ref` for `type` is probably the best you can get for the second table on this query.

There is one index that can be used (`possible_keys`) and it **is** used (`key`). The large value of `key_len` (`903`) tells me some of the columns used by this index (`idx8`) are strings and this makes the index less effective. However, you cannot improve this without making serious changes in the database structure and the code.

The value of `ref` (`tempdb.CA.agentLogin`) tells the value of what column of the already processed tables is used as reference for searching rows (using the `idx8` index) into the current table (join condition `CA.AgentLogin = O.agent_`).

The value of `rows` tells that MySQL estimates that for any row selected from the first table it will find `1` matching row in the second table. Again, this is an estimation but the small value is good nevertheless.

The value `using WHERE` of `extra` tells that using only the index (`idx8`) is not enough to identify the matching row(s). After the potential matching rows are identified in table `O` (condition `CA.AgentLogin = O.agent_`), the other conditions are evaluated for each of them (`CA.id_enterprise = O.id_enterprise AND O.Outcome_generated_time >CA.Call_Starttime AND O.Outcome_generated_time <= CA.NextCall`).

#### What you can improve

There are four conditions on the table join:

- `CA.AgentLogin = O.agent_`
- `CA.id_enterprise = O.id_enterprise`
- `O.Outcome_generated_time > CA.Call_Starttime`
- `O.Outcome_generated_time <= CA.NextCall`

The first two conditions can use an index (if it exists) to identify one or more matching rows. The last two conditions identify a range of potential matching rows.

All the columns of `O` used in these conditions appear in index `idx8`. But MySQL reports it uses only the value of `CA.agentLogin` to search rows using the index (column `ref` in the output of `EXPLAIN`).

MySQL can use [multiple-column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. This means, the `idx8` index can be used to identify rows based on the values of `agent_` only, `agent_` and `Outcome_generated_time` or on three columns it indexes. But **it cannot use `idx8` to identify rows based on their values in columns `agent_` and `id_enterprise`.**

Back to the list of join conditions (listed above), to make better use of indexes you need either to modify the definition of `idx8` to index the columns in the order `agent_`, `id_enterprise`, `Outcome_generated_time` or (if this is not possible or affects other queries) create another index.

#### What to do next

Create another index on table `Outcomes_final` with the columns in the correct order

```
ALTER table tempdb.Outcomes_final add index `idx10`
  (`agent_`, `id_enterprise`, `Outcome_generated_time`);
```

then run `EXPLAIN` again and verify that `key` is `idx10` and the columns `agent_`, `id_enterprise` are present in the `ref` column for the second table.

If this happens then you successfully optimized the query. It is also possible that the `using WHERE` clause is no more listed in the `Extra` column (and this is also good) but I cannot tell for sure.

If you created `idx8` and `idx9` only for this query then you can remove them safely. Otherwise, keep them or modify them but make sure they are used by queries. Unused indexes waste disk space and processing power (they are updated on each `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query).

---

That's basically all you can do to improve this query. However, with or without this improvement, a query that returns 2 million rows takes time no matter what database engine you use or what optimizations you try. It simply needs time to read the data from disk (this is a expensive operation) and send it through the network (this also takes time).